# how to add listener to autocompletetextview, android?

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am trying to add listener that will react when an item is selected on the autocompletetextview...can anyone help
//phonename is the autocompletetextview

```
PhoneName.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                Toast.makeText(check.this," selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }

            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            }
        });
```

Comment: have you tried for `TextWatcher`??

Comment: I am doing something similiar HERE!!! http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12854336/autocompletetextview-backed-by-cursorloader

Answer (score 112, accepted):

try this:

```
phoneName.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View arg1, int pos,
                long id) {
              Toast.makeText(check.this," selected", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

Comment: Using this Listener, if I have a list of 10 items, but while typing autocomplete only produces 1 of the items, once i click on that item, will the `pos` parameter be the index in the entire list, or only in what is displayed?

Comment: @JuiCe pos will be the index of the item displayed.

Comment: `Toast.makeText(Check.this, adapter.getItem(position).toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();`

Comment: Note: I had to have the `setOnItemSelectedListener` set in order to implement `setOnItemClickListener`.  Not sure why but it won't compile with just `setOnItemClickListener`.

Comment: @Prabs what will be the actual position of a item while typing?

Comment: The best answer ever

Answer (score 9):

In kotlin, this would be:

```kotlin
autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener { _, _, position, _ -> 
    // You can get the label or item that the user clicked:
    val value = adapter.getItem(position) ?: ""
    Toast.makeText(this, value, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

I also recommend you name your variables starting with a lowercase letter to not confuse them with types.

Answer (score 0):

**Kotlin :**

```
    v.autoCompleteTextView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
        Toast.makeText(requireContext(),"$position selected",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to get text of chosen item

```
phoneName.doOnTextChanged { text, start, before, count ->
        //do something with "text" variable
    }
```