# How can i dynamically change the the Visibility of the view second to visible

Tags: android

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="170dp"
        android:background="#fff" >

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/location_view"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/category_view"
            android:layout_below="@+id/category_view"
            android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/location"
            android:textSize="@dimen/autocomplettextview"
            />

        <AutoCompleteTextView
            android:id="@+id/category_view"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginTop="21dp"
            android:ems="10"
            android:hint="@string/category"
            android:textSize="@dimen/autocomplettextview"
            android:textColor="#000"
            >

            <requestFocus />
        </AutoCompleteTextView>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/getquote_button"
            android:layout_width="150dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:background="@drawable/getquote"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp" />

    </RelativeLayout>

<include layout="@layout/First_layout" 

    android:visibility="visible">
   </include>
<include layout="@layout/second_layout"
    android:visibility="invisible"

    />   
   </LinearLayout>
```

I wanted to make the second view to visible and visibility of first view to invisible on the item selected of the autocomplete View
As The User select the Item From the AutoComplete View List The Second Layout Gets Visible And The First Layout will be Invisible

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try `OnItemClickListener` for that AutoCompleteTextview.:

```
textView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() { 

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
            long arg3) {
        view2.setVisibility(View.Visible);
        view1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
});
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

assign your include tag an "ID" and use findViewById to get the reference and set Visibility to View.Visible.

```
<include layout="@layout/second_layout"
    android:id="@+id/second_view"
    android:visibility="invisible"
    />
```

in java:

```
   View view = findViewById(R.id.second_view);
   view.setVisibility(View.Visible);
```

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a button

```
Button one = (Button)findViewByID(R.id.ButtonID1);
Button two = (Button)findViewByID(R.id.ButtonID2);
```

on selection of your desired value in autocomplete - 
use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616812/how-to-add-listener-to-autocompletetextview-android)

and put

```
one.setVisibiity(View.GONE);
two.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
```

in its `onItemClick`

Comment: THIS ERROR is showing: error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)